# Generating unique URL to perform action

Tags: php, url, dynamic, hash, whmcs

We have purchased a WHMCS Billing Module that allows us to offer our clients free service trials. We however would like to allow the client to continue to renew the free trial as long as they want but they must remain active.

Ideally we would like to just send them an e-mail every X days with a link URL that will allow them to renew the free service for another period of time. The module already supports sending e-mail templates but I have never done any type of URL generation before.

What would I need to look into as far as generating unique URLs/hashes and performing an action when clicked? This doesn't really fall into the standard WHMCS hooks/api/etc. so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can simply use the same url with a few get parameters serialized and on the page unserialize and act accordingly.

Comment: Something like add a new .php file to the module called "renew.php" that reads GET params client + service and handles increasing the next due date by X days? Then in the e-mail just include site.com/whmcs/modules/trials/renew.php?client=xxx&service=xxx or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create [Addon Module](http://docs.whmcs.com/Addon_Module_Developer_Docs) renew_trail, for unique urls, when sending the email:

```
$token = md5(microtime() . $userid);
$url = $whmcs_url . 'index.php?m=renew_trail&token=' . $token;
```

When user clicks the url the token var will be passed as a get variable to renew_trail_clientarea() function.

using Addon Module will make it possible for you to track the clicks for example, and show a report in the renew_trail_output() function.